Images scales in Edge and Firefox, but in IE11 it goes wrong
I created a design with two images next to each other using Flexbox (css). In Edge and Firefox it looks good. The images are displayed nicely. When resizing the screen, the images scale well, both horizontally and vertically.
However in IE11 it does not scale well. The width scales as it should, but the height remains the same.
I have tried all kinds of things, but have no idea how to solve this problem.
Does anyone have a tip?
<section>
   <div class="flex">
      <div class="col-topnieuws post-media">
          <img src="images/cont/8663.jpg" alt="Description 1">
      </div>
      <div class="col-topnieuws post-media">
          <img src="images/cont/8664.jpg" alt="Description 2">
      </div>
   </div>
</section>

CSS:
.flex {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
 }

.flex .col-topnieuws {
   width: calc((100% / 2) - (50px / 2));
   margin-right: 25px;
   margin-bottom: 25px;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   flex: 1 1 200px;
}

.post-media {
   position: relative;
   overflow: auto;
}

img {
   width: auto;
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   border: none;
   line-height: normal;
   vertical-align: middle;
 }

UPDATE:
It's a little strange. If I add an a href Attribute around the image tag it goes fine, the image scaled as it should.
<section>
   <div class="flex">
     <div class="col-topnieuws post-media">
       <a href="#">
          <img src="images/cont/8663.jpg" alt="Description 1">
       </a>
     </div>
     <div class="col-topnieuws post-media">
       <a href="#">
          <img src="images/cont/8664.jpg" alt="Description 2">
       </a>
     </div>
   </div>
</section>


Well, the best advice is "don't use IE11".  I didn't know it supported "flex" at all.

I found it. Stupid me!
There is an double flexbox in the direction colomn. When I delete display: flex; and
flex-direction: column; everythings works fine.
